# NGINX try_files don't open file on location

Tags: nginx, wsdl, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

can you help me with resolving that issue, was trying to get the file by the url, but always geting 404: https://test.com/services/orders.svc
HELP HELP HELP HELP

> server.conf

```
map $request_method $external_services {
    GET     wsdl;
    POST    api;
    HEAD    wsdl;
}
server {
    server_name _;
    listen 80;
    charset utf-8;
    server_tokens off;
    gzip            on;
    gzip_types      text/plain application/xml text/css application/javascript;
    gzip_min_length 1000;
    if ($host ~* www\.(.*))
    {
        set $host_without_www $1;
        rewrite ^(.*)$ $scheme://$host_without_www$1 permanent;
    }
    # drop slashes
    if (!-d $request_filename)
    {
        rewrite ^/(.+)/+$ /$1 permanent;
    }
    location @wsdl {
      root /opt;
      include mime.types;
      types {
        'text/xml; charset=UTF-8' wsdl;
      }
      default_type 'text/xml; charset=UTF-8';
      try_files /services/testOrder.wsdl =404;
    }
    location @api {
        set $var app/hooks/order-changed;
        proxy_pass        http://api/$var;
        proxy_redirect    off;
    }
    location /services/orders.svc
    {
        try_files  /dev/null @$external_services;
    }
}
```

Comment: No matter what is the incoming request URI is, you are trying to serve any `GET` or `HEAD` request with the `/opt/services/testOrder.wdsl` file (which is probably does not exists according to your 404 response). And no matter what is the incoming request URI is, you are trying to serve any `POST` request via the `http://api/app/hooks/order-changed`, is it correct? BTW, where did you get that `/dev/null`?

Comment: its so stupid!!! I just copy file from /opt to /opt/services and its working! How is correct to change try_files /dev/null @$external_services;?

Comment: @IvanShatsky Thx you! How is correct to change try_files /dev/null @$external_services;

Comment: I suppose this `/dev/null` comes from [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/908086/nginx-directly-send-from-location-to-another-named-location). See my answer [below](https://serverfault.com/a/1100562/498657) why `try_files /dev/null @name` has no benefit over other variants like `try_files /nonexistent @name` and why using `try_files "" @name` can be a better choice.

Comment: Instead of `set $var app/hooks/order-changed; proxy_pass http://api/$var;` consider using `rewrite ^ /app/hooks/order-changed break; proxy_pass http://api;`